# Parse JQ output through external bash function?

Tags: bash, parsing, logging, jq, tail

I want to parse out data out of a log file which consist of JSON sting and I wonder if there's a way for me to use a bash function to perform any custom parsing instead of overloading `jq` command.

Command:

```
tail errors.log --follow | jq --raw-output '. | [.server_name, .server_port, .request_file] | @tsv'
```

Outputs:

```
8.8.8.8     80     /var/www/domain.com/www/public
```

I want to parse 3rd column to cut the string to exclude `/var/www/domain.com` part where `/var/www/domain.com` is the document root, and `/var/www/domain.com/subdomain/public` is the public `html` section of the site. Therefore I would like to leave my output as `/subdomain/public` (or from the example `/www/public`).

I wonder if I can somehow inject a bash function to parse `.request_file` column? Or how would I do that using `jq`?

I'm having issues piping out the output of any part of this command that would allow me to do any sort of string manipulation.

Comment: Only `domain.com` exactly, or do you want to trim the first three directories no matter what they are? Should the resulting 3rd column be `www/public` or `/www/public`? I'm making some assumptions in my answer, but a better question would provide an explicit example of the *desired* output, not just the current output.

Comment: `/www/public` would be the desired output.

Comment: BTW, options (like `--follow`) should always be before arguments (like `errors.log`); GNU tools allow it to be the other way around, but the [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) are explicit that only the options-first ordering is guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: hmm. This might be confusing so the desire output is the `/subdomain/public` which is `/www/domain.com` if the source was `www.example.com`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain an explicit counterexample (with both present output and desired output) for which you're concerned the existing answer may not behave as desired.

Comment: Insofar as I can understand your edits, the existing answer appears to be responsive. If that's not the case, please be explicit.

Comment: Ok, perhapt i will clarify that `/var/www` is the default sub-directory of Apache 2 on Debian os? Please, what's confusing?

Comment: Yes, I understand that `/var/www` is the default directory used by Apache. I don't understand why you're trying to inform me of that, as if knowing it would cause me to change my answer in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to iterate over the lines, and a [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to perform the desired modifications:

```
tail -f -- errors.log \
  | jq --raw-output --unbuffered \
       '[.server_name, .server_port, .request_file] | @tsv' \
  | while IFS=$'\t' read -r server_name server_port request_file; do
      printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$server_name" "$server_port" "/${request_file#/var/www/*/}"
    done
```

Note the use of `--unbuffered`, to force `jq` to flush its output lines immediately rather than buffering them. This has a performance penalty (so it's not default), but it ensures that you get output immediately when reading from a potentially-slow input source.

---

That said, it's also easy to remove a prefix in `jq`, so there's no particular reason to do the above:

```
tail -f -- errors.log | jq -r '
  def withoutPrefix: sub("^([/][^/]+){3}"; "");
  [.server_name, .server_port, (.request_file | withoutPrefix)] | @tsv'
```

Comment: I like the first option, but both will be super useful when i get to understand them. Please help me debug the first example. When I run first command, I don't get any output when log refreshes. Perhaps this brings me more to my last issue, not being able to pipe anything out of the tail?

Comment: Second option does work but removed only /var/. don't worry about details, i got those.

Comment: Gotcha -- that's all about buffering. If you have enough content, it'll eventually get flushed. See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009). If you're piping from `jq` to something other than the console, you'll want to use the `--unbuffered` flag.

Comment: Re: the second option, the `{3}` tells it how many pieces to remove. I tested it on my end before posting, and it removed the indicated number, so I'd need to see the details of how you implemented/tested to speak to any failure.

Comment: Works! You're the beast to me. Really appreciate it.